# CameraX - crash app on onPause() while recording video

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax, android-mediacodec

if minimize app while recording video - everything all right, but once I deploy the application, ерут getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-video encoding thread
Process: <pkgname>, PID: 12340
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2698)
    at androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture.videoEncode(VideoCapture.java:604)
    at androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture$2.run(VideoCapture.java:348)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Or
 if I stopped recording on onPause `videoCapture?.stopRecording()`, then getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-
Process: <pkgname>, PID: 9489
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:96)
    at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:108)
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera.openCaptureSession(Camera.java:874)
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera.onUseCaseReset(Camera.java:625)
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera$11.run(Camera.java:611)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

How right stop record video while minimize app???

here's my code:
I collect configurations:

```
CameraX.unbindAll()
    getDisplayMetrics()
    setPreviewConfig()

    when (typeCapture) {
        TYPE_IMAGE -> {
            setImageCapture()
            CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture)
        }
        TYPE_VIDEO -> {
            setVideoCapture()
            CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, videoCapture)
        }
    }
```

set videoConfig and videoCapture:

```
val videoCaptureConfig = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        setTargetAspectRatioCustom(screenAspectRatio)
        setTargetRotation(rotation)
    }.build()

    videoCapture = VideoCapture(videoCaptureConfig)
```

then I start recording video:

```
videoCapture?.startRecording(videoFile, 
CameraXExecutors.mainThreadExecutor(), recordListener)
```

on onPause() the errors I get are described above

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code, no way to know what's wrong by just seeing the stack trace.

Comment: @patrick.elmquist, upd post above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error when stoping the video on onPause. To solve it I added a delay before to call `super.onPause()` ( see : [android: camera onPause/onResume issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935292/android-camera-onpause-onresume-issue)).

1. Declare videoSavedListener

```
private VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedListener videoSavedListener= new VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onVideoSaved(@NonNull File file) {
        if(isRecording) {
            isRecording = false;
            // Do whatever you want
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull VideoCapture.VideoCaptureError videoCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {

    }
};
```

2. Add onClickListener

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if(!isRecording){
        videoCapture.startRecording(videoFile, CameraXExecutors.mainThreadExecutor(), videoSavedListener);
        isRecording = true;
     }else{
        videoCapture.stopRecording();
     }
});
```

3. Override onPause()

```
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if(isRecording){
            isRecording = false;
            videoCapture.stopRecording();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.onPause();
        }else
            super.onPause();
    }
```

> Please note that video recording use case is currently marked as
>   hidden in the API and is in a very preliminary state and subject to
>   change.

EDIT: With some devices the app still crash when calling `onPause()` with the videoCapture use case set. I added `CameraX.unbindAll()` to remove all the use cases before calling `super.onPause()`. Then, in the `onResume()` method I bind them again.

Answer (score -1):

Declare a boolean variable

```
public class MyClass{
private boolean isSafe;
private boolean isPending
onPause{
isSafe=false;
}
onPostResume{
isSafe=true;
if(isPending)
methodForDoingUrAction();
}
methodForDoingUrAction(){

if(isSAfe){
//do your process
isPending=false;
}
else
isPending=true;
}
}
```

Comment: thx, but how does this help me with stopping the video recording???

Comment: @Ruslan Medvedev if  you have logic to stop recording,then stop it when it enters the methodForDoingUrAction() in else case

Comment: it didn't change anything
I also get an error:
where FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-video encoding thread

Comment: What is this...?? Totally irrelevant!